# why java does not support dynamic variable dispatch

Tags: java, inheritance

Please excuse me if title is wrong. There are two class Test and TestChild1 where TestChild1 is inherited from Test. Both classes have a variable named "a". When I tried to access variable "a" through superclass variable which is instantiated with subclass object, it is giving the value that is initialized with in superclass not subclass.
following is the code that raised the doubt

```
class Test {
    public int a = 10;
}

class TestChild1 extends Test {
    public int a = 20;
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new TestChild1();
        System.out.println(test.a); // results in 10
    }
}
```

Please give me the reasons for this behavior. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Wow, that's pretty weird! Never knew that.

Comment: It doesn't because it doesn't. You would have to ask Jim Gosling. All you will get here is more or less uninformed opinion. Also, show me a language that does support it.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I didn't. I said 'more or less uninformed'. Don't misquote me and then ask me to defined your misquote. Saying that it's a language decision is certainly correct but also a mere tautology. Surely the OP wants to know why that decision was made? Only the designers know that.

Answer (score 9):

Because the Java designers decided to make methods polymorphic (and thus overridable), but not fields.

When you reference a field from an object, the *compiler* decides which field to use, based on the *declared* type of the variable, which, in this case, is `Test`.

When you refer to methods, the JVM, at runtime, chooses which method to call based on the *actual, concrete* type of the object which, in this case, is `TestChild`.

OO is all about encapsulation of state, so you should almost never expose fields to the outside anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The class TestChild1 has two variables with the same name. If you access them through Test you get the first one, from TestChild1 you get the second one.

To get your expected result, you should not declare a in the derived class. Instead you should initialize it in the costructor of the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your object as `Test`, not the subclass.  At compile time that means you refer to the base class which has 10.

Answer (score 0):

Because *behavior* is associated with methods and not with fields.

So, fields have static binding (in this case this, since test is of type `Test`, value of `a` is assigned with value 10). Whereas methods have dynamic binding.

Since, the variable `a` doesn't define the behavior of `Test` class, it is assigned the value as per its type and not as per its instance.

Answer (score 0):

**JB Nizet** have already said everything, but I will add this code for more understanding:

```
class Test {
    private int a = 10;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

class TestChild1 extends Test {
    private int a = 20;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new TestChild1();
        System.out.println(test.getA()); // results in 20
    }
}
```

So if you would encapsulate your fields, you would have expected behaviour.