# Instance looking up field / weird behaviour with variable assignment

Tags: java, python

I'm exploring method and variable inheritance in Java and specifically how instances of a class looks up fields (static variables).

However, I wasn't able to get the behaviour I expected in the Java fragment below.

More puzzlingly, running the same (?) thing written in Python gets me the expected results.

```java
class Up {

    public static int n = 1;
    public int m;

    public void setter() {
        System.out.println("I looked up " + this.n);
        this.m = this.n;
        System.out.println(this.m);
    }
}

class Sub extends Up {

    public static int n = 6;
    public int m = 5;

    public Sub() {
        super();
    }
}

class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub foo = new Sub();
        foo.setter();
        System.out.println(foo.m);
    }
}
```

```py
class Up:
    n = 1

    def setter(self):
        print("I looked up", self.n)
        self.m = self.n
        print(self.m)

class Sub(Up):
    n = 6
    m = 5

foo = Sub()
foo.setter()
print(foo.m)
```

The Python code ran as expected and printed out:

```
I looked up 6
6
6
```

The equivalent Java code however, printed out:

```
I looked up 1
1
5
```

I guess I have two problems here:

1. Why did Java interpret this.n as the field initialised in class Up instead of the actual class of foo, Sub?
2. After successfully looking up 1, Java should've bound foo.m to 1. Printing out this.m seems to indicate that it had, but printing out foo.m directly from the main method indicates that it hadn't, why is this?

I suspected that this is caused by the fact that Java "accesses variables in run-time" (I'm still wrapping my head around that), which I guess explains number 1, but I'm hoping that someone would explain to me what's happening behind number 2?

Comment: Because static fields aren't inherited.

Comment: `this.n` makes no sense because `n` is static and `this` is an instance. Java uses the *static* type of the instance to resolve it, so you're accessing `Up.n` there.

Comment: @Blorgbeard am I right to understand static type of the instance as meaning the class of the instance?

Comment: The *declared* class of the instance, yes - so for `this`, it's `Up` in this case. This happens at compile-time, because there is no inheritence / dynamic-dispatch for statics.

Comment: @Blorgbeard ah, alright, I get what you're saying!

Comment: @Blogbeard is this behaviour unique to statics though. I tried setting both ns up without the static keyword and the output's still the same thing?

Comment: Good point, I was concentrating on the "static". Only instance methods get dynamic dispatch - so nothing static, and no fields at all. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510878/why-java-does-not-support-dynamic-variable-dispatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS for the second question, you have two instance variables called "m". One declared in Class Up, and one declared in class Sub that hides the variable in Up. So when you call setter(), which is a method of Up, it uses the value of m found in Up (Up know nothing about the variables found in any of its subclasses).

But when you later print foo.m, since foo is an instacnce of Sub, it uses the value of m found in Sub, which is still 5.

Remove the declaration of m in class Sub and see what happens.

Comment: Got it. So Java interprets this.m in this case as the static field in Up, and when I was calling setter I was really modifying the static field m; foo was not touched at all?

Comment: No, m is not a static field in Up. It is an instance field.Each instance of Up will have its own individual m. Since setter() is a method of Up, that method knows nothing about instance fields of a subclass - it know only about instance fields of its own class (Up).

Comment: Hmm... so this.m is interpreted as an instance field of a particular instance of Up, even though no such instance exists?

Comment: Sure it exists. You created it here: `Sub foo = new Sub();`,  The variable foo is an instance of a subclass of Up, and therefore is an Up.The point is that Up knows nothing about the existence of a class named Sub, so methods defined in Up cannot know anything about variables other than those defined in Up.

Comment: Ah. I suddenly get it now.